# Merge lists to get a good overview

Tags: datatable, aggregateresult

I have two objects (one custom object "sales", two standard object "opportunity" and "account") and I have three lists with aggregateresults.

Can I merge these lists into one list?

The goal of the list is to give the sales reps a good overview of the current situation of the accounts around the planning.

### Apex

```
Public Class Plan220219_class {

    Public Summary1[] Summaries1 {get; set;}
    Public Summary2[] Summaries2 {get; set;}
    Public Summary3[] Summaries3 {get; set;}

    Public Plan220219_class() {

    agg1();

    agg2();

    agg3();

    }

    public void agg1() {
    AggregateResult[] results1 = [SELECT COUNT(OwnerId) CountAcc, Id FROM Account GROUP BY Id];
        Summaries1 = new List<Summary1>();
        FOR(AggregateResult ar1 : results1) {
            Summaries1.add(new Summary1(ar1));
        }
    }

    public void agg2() {
    AggregateResult[] results2 = [SELECT COUNT(Id) CountSales, SUM(Sales_amount__c) Sales_amount, contract2__r.contract1__r.account__r.Id FROM Sales__c GROUP BY contract2__r.contract1__r.account__r.Id];
        Summaries2 = new List<Summary2>();
        FOR(AggregateResult ar2 : results2) {
            Summaries2.add(new Summary2(ar2));
        }
    }

    public void agg3() {
    AggregateResult[] results3 = [SELECT SUM(Amount) Opp_Amount, Account.Id FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.Id];
        Summaries3 = new List<Summary3>();
        FOR(AggregateResult ar3 : results3) {
            Summaries3.add(new Summary3(ar3));
        }
    }

    public class summary1 {
        public Integer CountAcc {get; set;}
        public Id UId {get; set;}         

    public summary1 (AggregateResult ar1) {
        CountAcc = (Integer) ar1.get('CountAcc');
        UId = (Id) ar1.get('Id');       
        }
    }

    public class summary2 {
        public Integer CountSales {get; set;}
        public Double Sales_Amount {get; set;}      
        public Id UId {get; set;}

    public summary2 (AggregateResult ar2) {
        CountSales = (Integer) ar2.get('CountSales');
        Sales_Amount = (Double) ar2.get('Sales_amouont');        
        UId = (Id) ar2.get('Id');
        }
    }

    public class summary3 {
        public Double Opp_Amount {get; set;}      
        public Id UId {get; set;}

    public summary3 (AggregateResult ar3) {
        Opp_Amount = (Double) ar3.get('Opp_Amount');        
        UId = (Id) ar3.get('Id');
        }
    }

}
```

### Visualforce

```
<apex:page controller="Plan220219_class">

    <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries1}" var="summary1">
        {!summary1.UId} : {!summary1.CountAcc} <br/>
    </apex:repeat>

    <br/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries2}" var="summary2">
        {!summary2.UId} : {!summary2.CountSales} : {!summary2.Brutto_BWS} <br/>
    </apex:repeat>

    <br/>

    <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries3}" var="summary3">
        {!summary3.UId} : {!summary3.OPP_Amount} <br/>
    </apex:repeat>

</apex:page>
```

### RESULT Visualpage

List1 account overview:

0018E00000UqpQFQAZ : 1

0018E00000UqqZvQAJ : 1

0018E00000f8iJAQAY : 1

0018E00000XIp5hQAD : 1

0018E00000XrFPPQA3 : 1

0018E00000eMraBQAS : 1

0018E00000UqpQAQAZ : 1

0018E00000f5gMQQAY : 1

List2 sales of the accounts:

0018E00000UqpQFQAZ : 2 : 32000.0

0018E00000UqqZvQAJ : 2 : 453000.0

0018E00000UqpQAQAZ : 2 : 20000.0

List3 opps of the accounts:

0018E00000UqpQFQAZ : 1000.0

0018E00000eMraBQAS : 0.0

0018E00000UqpQAQAZ : 1000.0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The usual route is to use a *wrapper class* pattern, which you actually already have going here. Your `summary` classes, like this one,

```
public class summary2 {
    public Integer CountSales {get; set;}
    public Double Sales_Amount {get; set;}      
    public Id UId {get; set;}

public summary2 (AggregateResult ar2) {
    CountSales = (Integer) ar2.get('CountSales');
    Sales_Amount = (Double) ar2.get('Sales_amouont');        
    UId = (Id) ar2.get('Id');
    }
}
```

are really wrapper classes.

The way I would approach this is to define a new class, say `CompleteSummary`, that includes all of the summarized data points:

```
public class CompleteSummary {
    public Integer CountSales {get; set;}
    public Double Sales_Amount {get; set;}  
    public Integer CountAcc {get; set;}  
    public Double Opp_Amount {get; set;}        
    public Id UId {get; set;}
```

}

Then, build up a `Map<Id, CompleteSummary>` as you iterate through each of your `AggregateResult` lists. Each time through the loop, you can use your `UId` as a key to see if you've started building a `CompleteSummary` in the `Map` for this Id yet. If you have, you just add the keys from *this* sort of `AggregateResult` to that object; if not, you start a new `CompleteSummary`.

When you're done aggregating information, you can store a `List<CompleteSummary>` (just `summaryMap.values()`; you can have your wrapper class implement `Comparable` if you want to sort them), and display that list on your Visualforce page.